# How to set up a bottomnavigation that hide with slide to left when changing fragment?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I searched but nothing could answer my question.
I have a few fragments. In one of these fragments, I have a recycler view. When I click on one of the items I open a new fragment with a view but in this fragment, I want to hide the bottom nav.
The bottom nav is connected with my main activity layout which includes a container where the fragments are loaded. So when I click on the item it opens the new view of the item but with bottom nav. Im searching for a solution to hide this bottom nav with a slide to left and when back pressed it slides back from left to the centre of the view.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an onDestinationChange listener in the host activity as shown:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.detailActivity, R.id.originalResolutionFragment -> {
                binding.bottomNavigation.apply {
                    makeFadeTransition(300)
                    visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }
            else -> binding.bottomNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

You can see an example usecase [here](https://github.com/zedlabs/WallPortal/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tk/zedlabs/wallportal/ui/activity/MainActivity.kt)